# lodash _.findKey equivalent in Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I have a series of pieces in a game and at the beginning I store their store DIV complete with styling in an object with the respective key being an encrypted number. At the end of the game I check the piece that has been clicked on to see if its current z-index matches that of the original styling stored in the object.
Currently I am using lodash which works perfectly but I would like to remove lodash so as not to have to load this extra libary. My problem is, I simply can't translate the three lines of code into pure Javascript (or jQuery for that matter) - I'm quite a beginner and have now spent hours trying to resolve this. Any advice would be appreciated.
Here my "lodash" code:

```
var myVar = _.findKey(myObject, function (storedDIV) {
    return storedDIV.css('z-index') == clickedDIV.css('z-index');
});
```

Comment: Lodash is open source. You can copy the code for `findKey`

Comment: @jabba - super - worked perfectly, many thanks - just for everyon's information - doing it this way meant I had to write just "findKey" instead of "_.findKey" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a similar function to [`_.findKey()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#findKey) using `Object.keys` and `Array.find()`. The function accepts a predicate, or you can use the default identity predicate (`o => o`), but it doesn't support the other lodash `_.findKey()` shorthands.

```js
const findKey = (obj, predicate = o => o) => Object.keys(obj)
    .find(key => predicate(obj[key], key, obj))

// example 1 - passing a predicate
const users = {'barney':  { 'age': 36, 'active': true },'fred':    { 'age': 40, 'active': false },'pebbles': { 'age': 1,  'active': true }}
console.log(findKey(users, o => o.age < 40)) // barney

// example 2 - using default identity predicate
const flags = { a: false, b: true, c: false }
console.log(findKey(flags)) // b
```